# DSL connection keeps disconnecting in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, pppoe, dsl

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I start my DSL connection which requires a username and password using the command

```
sudo pon dsl-provider
```

It runs well for a few minutes and then it is disconnected. It shows the following messages on `plog`-

```
Remote message: Login incorrect
PAP authentication failed
Connection terminated.
Sent PADT
Modem hangup
```

I am sure I have entered the correct username and password what my ISP has provided me. It is automatically reconnected after 5-10 minutes. Why my login is rejected often and cannot let me connect to the internet?

Comment: This is probably something that you should call you ISP about.